# How do i iterate through CSV in jmeter creating new thread

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, jsr223

I am trying to come up with jmeter setup in which i want to read entire csv file that has 200000 rows and i want iterate through each rows creating new thread since i am using JSR223 pre-processor that requires new thread for removing empty parameters from the request body. For some reason when i use while loop then only first test passes and rest of the tests fails as JSR223 pre-processor keeps on reading previous thread. I have also un-checked **cached compiled script if available** but still no luck. I also want to add that when i explicitly specify the number of threads as 100 out of 200000 then all of my 100 test passes as it reads new thread each time. Below is the screenshot of my set up:

**This Fails** -

[image]

**This Passes -**

[image]

[image]

JSR223 Pre-Processor Script that i am using:

```
def request = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
def newRequest = evaluate(request.inspect())
request.body.each { entry ->
    if (entry.getValue().equals('')) {
        newRequest.body.remove(entry.getKey())
    }
}
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(newRequest).toPrettyString(), '')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

Console log when using while controller

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this :

```
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
```

By:

```
def arguments = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments();
sampler.setArguments(arguments);
```

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to provide a comprehensive answer without seeing:

1. Your [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) condition stanza
2. First 3 lines of your CSV file
3. Your [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup
4. Your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler parameters or body

Double check the following:

1. Compare HTTP Request sampler body for 1st and 2nd requests under the While Controller
2. JMeter Variables originating from the CSV Data Set Config (you can inspect them using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and View Results Tree listener combination)
3. [Enable debug logging for the While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/), it might be the case it is not doing what you expect, it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.control.WhileController" level="debug" />
   ```

Comment: I apoligize but i don't know what to do. I tried everything that you mentioned. For 1. I tried checking request sampler and the 1st request has request body and 2nd request has empty request body under the while controller. 2. For DS it doesn't even show up in VRT 3. I have added screenshot above

Comment: My CSV is quite huge even the rows are very big so it would be impossible to share here. However i did try log.info("---->"+request) and i am able to see the request getting populated from each CSV rows. The line that gives a lot of trouble is this - > sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments().